# Navigation on user profile reputation page is broken

Tags: bug, profile-page, navigation-arrows, navigation

When visiting the reputation change page on a user profile page, you can navigate forwards and backwards using the pagination buttons at the bottom, but you can't navigate back using the browser's back button anymore.

Test here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation

This only happens when going back from page 2.

Tested on Chrome on Windows

Comment: Was this ever possible? I seem to recall this working the same before. I do agree that using the back/forward should work, I just wonder if it doesn't need to be a feature-request instead.

Comment: @VLAZ well, even if so, inability to go back to page 1 from page 2 via browser navigation even if all pages create a history entry sounds like a bug to me :) But it may have been "always broken" indeed.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox on Windows.

Comment: This has been the case since the dawn of time. Going back from page 2 to the first page, which has no query portion (no `?page=…`) always loads page 2 from cache. Not since the dawn of time exactly but it certainly has been like that for about a decade now.